# Entity Framework AddOrUpdate

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, facebook, entity-framework

I tried to insert the data into database from Facebook Graph search API by using EF AddOrUpdate. It is weird the following exception happened.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Posts'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Posts'. The duplicate key value is (100000544976851_913461492015341).
>   The statement has been terminated.

The code is very simple:

```
        H2GO db2 = new H2GO();
        if (obj != null)
        {
            ICollection<Post> posts = new Collection<Post>();
            foreach (var data in obj.data)
            {
                var post = new Post
                {
                    ID = data.id,
                    Tag = tag,
                    Content = data.message,
                    User = data.from.name,
                    Type = 2,
                    TagDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data.created_time),
                };
                db2.Posts.AddOrUpdate(p => p.ID, post);
            }
            db2.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: ID is probably the only column that's part of your primary key

Comment: ID is the only primary key. This exception should not be happened because I use EF AddOrUpdate. If the ID is existed in database, it should be updated, right?

Comment: It should. What is the table and index definition?

Comment: Very simple table with only primary key, no index at all

Comment: This exception will happened once around 1 hours, I think it will not affect my business logical too much. Maybe it's a bug of Entity frame. God knows the reason

Comment: Try `db2.Posts.AddOrUpdate(p => p.ID, posts)` outside of your foreach. It should do the same thing but wondering if it'll make a difference.

Comment: Thanx artm, I wrote it originally like the way you provided, it doesn't work :D

Answer (score 0):

I see it has been a while, but I actually had this happen when I marked my model incorrectly and had a two part key and the database had only a one part key. So my model said this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The user identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the plan identifier. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The plan identifier.
    /// </value>
    [Key]
    public string PlanId { get; set; }
```

However, a user can only have one plan at a time, so the database said this:

[image]

It was a dumb mistake on my part and one I found quickly, but ... hopefully this helps someone out.